# A BaseActivity to render toolbar and navigation drawer

Tags: java, beginner, android, layout

I'm new to Android programming and this is my first project so I'm not sure if this is the correct method of rendering the toolbar or the navigation of the drawer on the screen:

So I have a BaseActivity class that has the methods `displayToolbar()` and `displayDrawer()` to display the ToolBar and the Navigation Drawer respectively like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    // Renders the app toolbar
    void displayToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    // Renders the app navigation drawer and the toolbar
    void displayDrawer() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer != null && drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_scan:
                Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(scanIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_create:
                Intent createIntent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
                startActivity(createIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_history:
                Intent historyIntent = new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(historyIntent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I have other Activities that inherit from BaseActivity. Activities which have a drawer are like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)
        displayToolbar();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And an activity that displays a drawer:

```
public class SomeActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)
        displayDrawer(); // Displays the toolbar and the drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The layout files of the activities that display the toolbar have the following:

```
<include layout="@layout/app_toolbar" />
```

Activities with a navigation drawer use this root ViewGroup:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> ... </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**My Question: Is this the correct way to display the drawer and/or the toolbar or should I be using some other way? Also additionally, is my way of providing navigation through the drawer correct?**

Comment: Yes. this is correct way to implement toolbar and navigation drawer at base level. I don't find any issue with this method.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the correct way to inherit parent class methods in child class.